# Sending Messages through Microsoft Graph API with SchemaExtension Data

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for some help formatting schema extension data in Microsoft's Graph API. I've been able to successfully send Office 365 messages in code and through the Graph Explorer using this body:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test Subject",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "Test Body "
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "foo@email.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I created a schema extension and promoted it to "Available" status. I can query the extension to verify it's available and get this response body:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "extc5bnq6uk_TestExtension",
            "description": "Test Extension",
            "targetTypes": [
                "Message"
            ],
            "status": "Available",
            "owner": "mysecretclienttenantgoeshere",
            "properties": [
                {
                    "name": "ValueOne",
                    "type": "String"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ValueTwo",
                    "type": "String"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So far I haven't been able to append extension data to a new message. I've tried formatting my request body like this:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test Subject",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "Test Body "
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "foo@email.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "extc5bnq6uk_TestExtension": {
      "ValueOne": "TestValue",
      "ValueTwo": "TestValue"
    }
  }
}
```

and like this:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test Subject",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "Test Body "
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "foo@email.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "extensions":[
    {
        "extc5bnq6uk_TestExtension" : {
            "ValueOne" : "TestValue"
            "ValueTwo" : "TestValue"
        }
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Both formats return a 400 code with response body:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBodyRead",
        "message": "The property 'extc5bnq6uk_TestExtension' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "21792fd0-44d1-42aa-8d51-f8abc92cbd04",
            "date": "2018-08-14T16:39:31"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm posting to this URL in the graph explorer:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

and to the "messages" and "sendMail" endpoints in code.

Comment: See wepage:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/opentypeextension

Comment: That documentation is for open type extensions, which are working fine.

Comment: Not sure what isn't working.   See : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/opentypeextension_get

Comment: That is also for open types @jdweng. This question is specific to schema extensions. Here's the documentation I'm following: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_schema_groups

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler .  And capture the good results and the bad to see if you see a pattern.  The link is using http 1.1.  Not sure what you code is sending.  Http 1.0 is stream mode while http 1.1 is chunk mode.  Chunk Mode requires send a Next Chunk message, otherwise, a timeout occurs.  I have never gotten 1.1 to work with a httpclient in c#.  I do not know what client is being used in your code.  But using a sniffer may give more info.  You may want to change 1.1 to 1.0 and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Known Limitations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#extensions) of the documentation. Certain resource types, including messages, have to be done in two stages, an initial post and then a follow up patch.

Creating the message and then patching with this JSON returned a valid response.

```
{
    "extc5bnq6uk_TestExtension": {
        "ValueOne": "Test Value One",
        "ValueTwo": "Test Value Two"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, another limitation for schema extensions on messages is that they can't be used to filter messages, which is what I was ultimately after.

> Filtering on schema extension properties (using the $filter
>   expresssion) is not supported for Outlook entity types - contact,
>   event, message, or post.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff

Based on your question you posted, you have created a schemaExtension successfully. I think you want to send an email with this schemaExtension, but when you send an email with this schemaExtension, we get the 400 code in the response.

Based on my test, I think we can use the request body as blow.

1.Create a schemaExtension like this:

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#schemaExtensions/$entity",
   "id":"{extensionId}",
   "description":"sample description",
   "targetTypes":[
       "Message"
    ],
   "status":"Available",
   "owner":"{owner id}",
   "properties":[
      {
          "name":"p1",
          "type":"String"
      },
      {
          "name":"p2",
          "type":"String"
      }
    ]
  }
```

2. Create a message

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

```
{
   "message":{
      "subject":"Meet for lunch?",
      "body":{
          "contentType":"Text",
          "content":"The new cafeteria is open."
       },
      "toRecipients":[
          {
              "emailAddress":{
                  "address":"{toRecipients email address}"
              }
          }
      ],
      "extensions":[
          {
              "@odata.type":"Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
              "extensionName":"{extensionName}",
              "p1":"Wingtip Toys",
              "p2":"10000"
          }
      ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems":"false"
}
```

3. when we send this message with the request, we will get the 202 code. The {toRecipients email address} will receive the email.

Comment: You created a schema extension in step 1 - but you're not actually using it when you send the message. Instead you create an open type extension with the same properties. Schema Extensions have to be patched in with a second request. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#extensions

Comment: OK, I checked my answer and read the content that you refer to. You are right. You can mark your answer as answer